# repaint the frame that contain GlsurfaceView

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es, sdk

I have a GLSurfaceView, when the user click a button, it will draw some triangles with default color.
Then when the user selects a color from my inflater menu, it will re-draw the triangles with that particular color. 
It works in a weird way, at first it does draw the triangles, and when i select a different color, it doesn't repaint with different color. However, when i turn off my phone and turn back on, the color changed.

Here is my code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.issm_menu,menu);

        return true;
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.menu_about:          
                Toast.makeText(ISSM.this, "ISSM Application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.cl_autumn:
                colorMap.setAutumn();
                drawFigure();
                return true;

            case R.id.cl_bone:
                colorMap.setBone();
                drawFigure();
                return true;

                default:
                       return true;
     }

    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        this.fillBuffer();
        drawFigure();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    public void drawFigure()
    {
        mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this, buff, size, colorMap);;
        frame.addView(mGLView);
    }
```

I want that as soon as i hit the color in my menu, the color should change, i do not want to turn off and turn on (by the way, not completely power off, just like sleep and wake up)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I need to called frame.removeView() first then add another view.